# Python argparse example?

Tags: python, python-3.x, argparse

I'm trying to learn argparse in order to use it in my program, the syntax should be like this:

```
-a --aLong <String> <String>
-b --bLong <String> <String> <Integer>
-c --cLong <String>
-h --help
```

I have this code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#coding: utf-8

import argparse

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Lorem Ipsum')
    parser.add_argument('-a','--aLong', help='Lorem Ipsum', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-b','--bLong', help='Lorem Ipsum', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-c','--cLong', help='Lorem Ipsum', required=False)
    parser.add_argument('-h','--help', help='Lorem Ipsum', required=False)
    parser.parse_args()
```

The question is, I read in the official doc, saw YouTube videos, etc, but I couldn't understand how can I determine the number of "sub-arguments" of the "main-argument"?

Example: `myApp.py -b Foobar 9000`, how can I set that `-b` must have two "sub-arguments", and how can I get the values, `Foobar` and `9000`?

And another doubt, I know I can set an argument to be `required` or not, but I wanted to make my program only executes when **at least one** argument is passed, any of the four mentioned.

Maybe it's a stupid question, but sorry, I can't understand it, and hopefully there is someone here with "teacher powers" to explain it.

Comment: You should be able to achieve what you've mentioned using Argument Groups - http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#argument-groups.

Comment: `argument-groups` won't help.  They affect the `help` display, but don't affect parsing. Testing after parsing as FMc does is the way to ensure one of the 3 arguments is given.  Mutually exclusively groups can be used to prevent more than 1 of the group being used, but the OP wants 'at least one'.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
import argparse

# Use nargs to specify how many arguments an option should take.
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
ap.add_argument('-a', nargs=2)
ap.add_argument('-b', nargs=3)
ap.add_argument('-c', nargs=1)

# An illustration of how access the arguments.
opts = ap.parse_args('-a A1 A2 -b B1 B2 B3 -c C1'.split())

print(opts)
print(opts.a)
print(opts.b)
print(opts.c)

# To require that at least one option be supplied (-a, -b, or -c)
# you have to write your own logic. For example:
opts = ap.parse_args([])
if not any([opts.a, opts.b, opts.c]):
    ap.print_usage()
    quit()

print("This won't run.")
```

Comment: OP has `python-3.x` tag, but this answer is Python 2.

Comment: Not quite there yet: in Python 3 [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#filter) returns an iterator, not a list. You should write `if not any([opts.a, opts.b, opts.c]):` instead.

Comment: Thanks, I got it now. Just a little doubt: I was trying to use something like this: `'-a', '--aLong'`, but if I do that, when I call `opts.a` it gives me an error - `AttributeError: 'Namespace' object has no attribute 'a'`, so I have to call `opts.aLong`, why?

Comment: Add a dest argument ```parser.add_argument('-a','--aLong', dest='a' ...)```

Comment: OP also wants `-b` to accept 2 strings and 1 integer.  `argparse` can't handle that directly.  A custom action could do that, but that's an advanced topic.

Comment: Nice, practical example.

Answer (score 2):

The key to this is to define a required, mutually exclusive group.

```
import argparse

# Use nargs to specify how many arguments an option should take.
ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()
group = ap.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
group.add_argument('-a', nargs=2)
group.add_argument('-b', nargs=3)
group.add_argument('-c', nargs=1)


# Grab the opts from argv
opts = ap.parse_args()

# This line will not be reached if none of a/b/c are specified.
# Usage/help will be printed instead.

print(opts)
print(opts.a)
print(opts.b)
print(opts.c)
```

Comment: Your required group means that exactly one of the 3 is required.  The OP wanted 'at least one'.